# Error no routes matches whit the controller and action corrects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I want to make a simple submit, ideally with no routes, to insert a sample into a database, but I am having some trouble.

This is the index of finance:

#### index.html.erb(finance path)

```
<%= form_for(@place,:url => new_place_finance_path,:method => :put) do |f| %>

  <%= f.text_field :place %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

If possible I don't want create a member, how do I make in routes:

```
resources :finances do
  member do
    put :new_place
  end
end
```

and my controller of finances:

```
def index
  @finances = Finance.all
  respond_with @finances
  @place = Place.new
end
```

and action new_place:

```
def new_place
  @place = Place.create(params[:place])
  @place.save
  if @place.save
    redirect_to finances_path,:notice => 'Lugar criado com sucesso.'
  else
    redirect_to finances_path,:notice => 'Falha ao criar lugar.'
  end 
end
```

I'm getting this error:

```
No route matches {:action=>"new_place", :controller=>"finances", :id=>nil}
```

When I execute rake routes:

```
new_place_finance PUT    /finances/:id/new_place(.:format) finances#new_place
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some unusual things in here.  If you want to create a new place, you would usually do this in routes.  If finance can have many places, then it would be like so...

```
resources :finances do
  resources :places
end
```

This will create a method called new_finance_place(@finance) that will take you to the new form.  And it will create another url to the /finances/:finance_id/posts that will expect a POST - it will call the create method in the PostsController.

From the new form, you will be able to write:

```
<%= form_for [@finance, @place] do |f| %>
```

Comment: +1 Exactly.  When you are riding the rails if you don't follow the conventions you fall off the rails.  Also this form should be in `_form.html.erb` that is included by `new.html.erb` and `edit.html.erb` not in `index` as you have it.

Answer (score 0):

`new_place_finance_path` needs a finance object in order to be evaluated correctly.  In the routes you pasted above

```
 new_place_finance PUT    /finances/:id/new_place(.:format) finances#new_place
```

so `new_place_finance_path(@finance)` will replace `:id` by @finance.id (or `to_param` if you created that method in the model)